# Weird error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLElement] has no method 'getAttribute'

Tags: javascript

I get the above error when I run this line of JavaScript (And thisMaxNode holds an HTML Element object with an attribute of `data-max="10"` or another number):

```
var thisMax = parseFloat(thisMaxNode.getAttribute('data-max'));
```

Isn't the `HTMLElement` object **exactly** what should have the method `getAttribute`?

Comment: Since 'data-max' is not a standard HTML attribute, it raises the question, what kind of HTML Element is `thisMaxNode`?

Comment: @Dancrumb: `data-` attributes are a feature of HTML5, and would be a custom attribute in HTML4. http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder if thisMaxNode actually contains an array of one HTML Element.  Array, of course, doesn't have a getAttribute method.

Comment: Aha, that was it! I didn't realize it was an Array of one element, even when `console.log` ging it out, I missed the brackets. Thanks! Using `thisMaxNode[0]` works perfectly.

Comment: Good guess... any idea why `thisMaxNode` was reported as `Object [object HTMLElement]`?

Comment: Maybe it means `Object(Array) [ Object(HTMLElement) ]` ? Maybe those brackets represent the array of one HTMLElement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're assuming too much. Take a step back and start confirming things.

What does `alert( thisMaxNode.nodeType )` give you? `1`? If not, it's not an element node and perhaps a nodeList or a whitespace node... more code would help.